# merge two javascripts into one foreach

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have javascript in my laravel blade view. Im wondering if i can merge these two scripts into one.
Script display graph in each bootstrap tabs.

Script first:

```
var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart( "chart_visits", {
        "dataProvider": [
            @foreach($results as $result)
                {
                    "date": "{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->time)) }}",
                    "value": '{{ $result->stats->visits }}'
                },
            @endforeach
        ]
    } );
```

Script second:

```
var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart( "chart_visits", {
        "dataProvider": [
            @foreach($results as $result)
                {
                    "date": "{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->time)) }}",
                    "value": '{{ $result->stats->bounceRate }}'
                },
            @endforeach
        ]
    } );
```

And this is my view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#bounce" data-toggle="tab"> Bounce rate </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#visits" data-toggle="tab"> Visits </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="visits">
        <div class="chartdiv" id="chart_visits"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="bounce">
        <div class="chartdiv" id="chart_bounce"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only if could make some "interface" for both arrays, ex: `$result->stats->visits` and `$result->stats->bounceRate` to be something like `$result->value` then you would just need an include for the chart generation

Comment: @ka_lin i can you paste me example Please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is jquery function `extend`

Script that is same for both and i dont want to dry:

```
var config = {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginRight": 40,
            "marginTop": 60,
            "marginLeft": 40,
            "autoMarginOffset": 0,
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
        };
```

First script that will extend duplicated values in both script:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chart_leads", jQuery.extend({}, config, {
            "dataProvider": [
                    @foreach($results as $result)
                {
                    "date": "{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->time)) }}",
                    "value": '{{ $result->stats->leads }}'
                },
                @endforeach
            ]
        } ));
```

Second script that will extend duplicated values in both script:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chart_visits", jQuery.extend({}, config, {
            "dataProvider": [
                    @foreach($results as $result)
                {
                    "date": "{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result->time)) }}",
                    "value": '{{ $result->stats->visits }}'
                },
                @endforeach
            ]
        } ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly easiest way to do what you want is to simply create plain array from collection of objects and iterate over that. Something like:

```
var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart( "chart_visits", {
    "dataProvider": [
        @foreach($results as $result)
        {
            "date": "{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result['date'])) }}",
            "value": "{{ $result['value'] }}"
        },
        @endforeach
    ]
} );
```